# How to drill down the object tracking instances for standalone java applications using AppDynamics?

Tags: java, profiling, appdynamics

Data is not loading from standalone java applications to agent controller, but only say java agent is connected successfully and waiting for data to load.

In Autodetection and Object tracing dashboard tabs, not able to view the detail or drill down the object tracking instances for standalone Java applications.

Configured adding some of the fully qualified class names from the application.

Please advice, do I need to do any other settings to get the drill down feature?

Comment: did you try making any request to your app and check the agent logs ?